# Wrong PATH in init script on boot

Tags: bash, boot, init.d, path, rc.d

Since the update of the System on my Synology NAS (x86),
I have some problems with my startup scripts.

The Bash scripts are stored in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`.
The scripts were executed for sure, 
because I have a Server running on root and it's starting without any problems.

But my other server executables doesn't start properly if I put them in the "su" command to start it with another user.

The commands that are executed in the scripts are following:

```
su admin -c /volume1/homes/admin/subsonic/subsonic.sh
```

The Bash script is running without any problems, but the script starts java with the specific commands and there it can't find the path of java.

```
su admin -c "screen -dmS ncdc ncdc"
```

On this line the problem is that the system can't find `screen`'s path.
If I start it without `su` so that it will be running as root, then it works.

**UPDATE**

If I start the command with a minus, then I also get this behaviour:

```
root@schreda-NAS:~ # su - admin -c "screen -dmS test test"
-bash: screen: command not found
```

The path value will be set by `/etc/profile`. I don't override the path on `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Have you tried inheriting admin's environment, with `su - admin -c "screen yadda yadda"`?

Comment: sure. but with the minus (-) it doesn't work even if the system is running and i start it manualy via ssh. then i get:
`root@schreda-NAS:~ # su - admin -c "screen -dmS test test"
-bash: screen: command not found`

Comment: Fair enough.  Is there any reason not to just invoke `screen` with its absolute path?